# Official Windows Server 2003 ISO wont boot

Tags: windows-server-2003, installation, windows-server-2003-r2, iso

One of our old servers just crashed (HP PowerEdge SC1430) and (as always) the original CDs cannot be found...

We downloaded the instalation ISO from [DELL](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R131815&fileId=2731115691&osCode=WNET&productCode=poweredge-1430sc&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM) and the Official Windows Server 2003 ISO from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/download/details.aspx?id=21700), but the Microsoft ISO wont boot either burning it to a CD/DVD or trying to mount it from Virtual Box, or booting from Dell's CD and then inserting the ISO image when asked

Do you know if there is a special method to make the WS2003 CD disk?

Regards....

Comment: That's not the Windows Server 2003 installation iso, that's the Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 installation iso. That won't install Windows Server 2003, it will install Service Pack 2 for Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Mmm do you know where can we download the instalation ISO? any standar version (R1 or R2) will do...

Comment: Msdn, no longer on vlsc portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cd 1 boot, not Cd2 for R2.

Check your download to validate what its, as you can see the boot file on it.

Be sure its not just SP2 you downloaded. (In those days they offered iso with only the SP on it). People tried to slipstream them, but its not bootable.

Comment: It's just the SP2 installation iso.

Comment: @joeqwerty Oh ok! Well, problem solved :), and he will need a msdn account to get that iso, vlsc no longer offer it

Comment: So that is just the SP2 update package? no the SP2 complete instalation ISO?

Comment: @Chico3001 Yes, and for a obscure reason the iso are hard to get. The only I know that still have it is with a msdn subscription. Do you have some friend near you that can just copyou the cd ? as you have the license

Comment: I have a MSDN subscription, im downloanding the ISO images but there many variations (KN, R2 with SP2 and just R2) any ideas on what are the differences on each one?

Comment: Get R2 normal to be sure :) KN is the north korean version.